# If $\varphi(n)\mid n-1$ then prove that there exist no prime such that $p^2\mid n$

Tags: number-theory

Can anyone help me with this!?
If $n=p_1^{k_1},p_2^{k_2},\ldots $
Then I applied the given condition of divisibility of $\varphi(n)$ but can't reach to a conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* If $p^2 \mid n$, then $p \mid \phi(n)$.

Indeed, if $p^e$ is the power of $p$ appearing in the factorization of $n$, then $\phi(n)=\phi(p^e)\cdots=p^{e-1}(p-1)\cdots$.

Comment: Can you explain how?

Answer (score 1):

First, note that $\phi$ multiplicative. Then if $n=p_1^{k_1}\cdots p_m^{k_m}$, then $\phi(n)=\phi(p_1^{k_1})\cdots\phi(p_m^{k_m})$.

I believe you can prove that if for some prime $p$ and some $k\in\mathbb{Z^+}$, and $k>1$, then $p|\phi(p^k)$.

So suppose that some $k_i$ is greater than $1$. Then $p_i|\phi(p_i^{k_i})\hspace{0.2cm}|\phi(n)\hspace{0.2cm}|n-1$. But also, $p|n$. So, prime $p$ should be equal to $1$. Absurd....

Answer (score 1):

we know that $n-\varphi(n)=\Pi\, p_i^{k_i-1}(\Pi\,p_i-\Pi\,(p_i-1))$ so if there is $k_i>1$ on the one hand we have $p_i|n-\varphi(n)$ and in the second one we know that  $p_i|n$ then, $p_i|\varphi(n)$. So $p_i|n-1$ and $p_i|n$  ---> absurd so $k_i=1~~\forall i$

Answer (score 1):

If $p^2 \mid n$, then $p \mid \varphi(n)$, but obviously $p \nmid n-1$ and so $\varphi(n) \nmid n-1$.